# How to prioritise columns based on overall significance level of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, priority-queue

How should I select columns based on significance level and which factors should I choose to decide the priority of the column of the given DataFrame

```
    A        B       C       D       E       F       G       H
5   61.0    77.0    40.0    46.0    60.0    73.0    66.0    1.0
4   60.0    51.0    49.0    59.0    59.0    67.0    69.0    3.0
3   35.0    32.0    48.0    57.0    43.0    34.0    34.0    4.0
2   17.0    16.0    22.0    12.0    15.0    5.0     5.0     1.0
1   10.0    7.0     11.0    3.0     4.0     5.0     8.0     4.0
```

At first, each index is a rating by the users for different functionalities (columns). I concatenated the `count_values` of each column and now trying to understand which functionalities(columns) are more relevant to the users. From the above df, I have to select the top three columns.

If anyone needs further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Without it, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @piRSquared just made some changes, please let me know if I need to explain anything.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. What is each row in your table? Did the `count_values` for each column represent up votes from users? I think you need to provide a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to do here: where do you get your initial data, and what you want the output of your process to be. Right now, I have only the vaguest idea of what you're doing.